# Alternative for $errcontext argument of error handler in php

Tags: php, function, magento

I am upgrading php version from **7.0.3 to 7.2.33**

I can see that `"$errcontext argument of error handler"` is deprecated

& i found that on the file in `Magento 1 framework` uses it like below

```
 public function errorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, $errcontext)
{
    $errorLevel = error_reporting();

    if ($errorLevel & $errno) {
        
        $this->log($errstr, $priority, array('errno'=>$errno, 'file'=>$errfile, 'line'=>$errline, 'context'=>$errcontext));
    }

    if ($this->_origErrorHandler !== null) {
        return call_user_func($this->_origErrorHandler, $errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, $errcontext);
    }
    return false;
}
```

**According to PHP docs :-
The $errcontext argument contains all local variables of the error site. Given its rare usage, and the problems it causes with internal optimisations, it has now been deprecated.
Instead, a debugger should be used to retrieve information on local variables at the error site.**

How do i modify this function, so that it won't throw an warning & work fine ?

Let me know if any questions.

Answers appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Remove `$errcontext` from your function and consider refactoring `$this->log()` to eliminate the context key there is a strict requirement for a context parameter:

```php
     public function errorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
    {
        $errorLevel = error_reporting();
    
        if ($errorLevel & $errno) {
            
            $this->log($errstr, $priority, array('errno'=>$errno, 'file'=>$errfile, 'line'=>$errline, 'context'=>'Context not supported or deprecated'));
        }
    
        if ($this->_origErrorHandler !== null) {
            return call_user_func($this->_origErrorHandler, $errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline);
        }
        return false;
    }
```